# Images from a folder are not being displayed when the html img tag is put inside a PHP loop

Tags: php, html, image, loops

I have a set of 8 jpg images in a folder and when I try to display each one of them using a for loop in PHP, I get a set of broken icons.

Path to the images folder is: `C:\xampp\htdocs\images`

The images are named as: `tn_1.jpg, tn_2.jpg, tn_3.jpg ..... tn_8.jpg`

```
<?php
  for ($i=1; $i<=8; $i++) {
    echo '<img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\images\tn_'.$i.'.jpg"/><br>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: change echo '<img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\images\tn_'.$i.'.jpg"/><br>'; to echo '<img src="images\tn_'.$i.'.jpg"/><br>';

Comment: You are using an absolute reference to the file on your local machine, not a path to the file within the web root. @Satya's answer may resolve this, depending on where the file actually is. 

There are important reasons why you can't publish absolute paths to local files in HTML via a web server.

Comment: @Satya Not working

Comment: @bargad right click on broken icons to see what is the link it is pointing to , and see if your files are there

Comment: @Satya Ok did that. Got Error 404 and this is the url: localhost:8080/images\tn_1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close! Your htdocs folder is the root folder for your web service, so you can just do:

```
<?php

for ($i=1;$i<=8;$i++) {
    echo '<img src="/images/tn_'.$i.'.jpg"/><br>';
}
```

Comment: Edit: slash direction in the image path.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change it to something like this :

```
echo '<img src="\\images\\tn_'.$i.'.jpg"/><br>';
```

because the character `\` might be treated as an escape character there.